# Angular $resources Cancel requests : $q

Tags: angularjs, request

I'm trying to understand...
How can I implement a requests cancell for this kind of services.

I was reading, that I shoud use $q.defer()

```
angular.module('App').service('TService', function ($resource, portal) {
return $resource(portal.getUrlServer() + 'api/T/:id', { id: '@Id' }, {
    T_GET: {
        method: 'GET',
        params:{
            id_turno: '@id_turno',
        },
        url: portal.getUrlServer() + 'api/T/T_GET/'
    },
    G_GET_Turno: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
             id_tramite_relevado : '@Id_Tramite_Relevado'
        },
        url: portal.getUrlServer() + 'api/T/G_GET_Turno/'
    },
});
```

What I want to do is when any method is called twice, I just want to let run the last called and cancel the other requests.

Comment: Just a thought, but another approach is to disable buttons/links/etc after a click so that you would not be able to call a method twice.

Answer (score 0):

From [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#pendingRequests) docs:

> If an action's configuration specifies that it is cancellable, you can cancel the request related to an instance or collection (as long as it is a result of a "non-instance" call).

```
// ...defining the `Hotel` resource...
var Hotel = $resource('/api/hotel/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
  // Let's make the `query()` method cancellable
  query: {method: 'get', isArray: true, cancellable: true}
});

// ...somewhere in the PlanVacationController...
...
this.onDestinationChanged = function onDestinationChanged(destination) {
  // We don't care about any pending request for hotels
  // in a different destination any more
  this.availableHotels.$cancelRequest();

  // Let's query for hotels in '<destination>'
  // (calls: /api/hotel?location=<destination>)
  this.availableHotels = Hotel.query({location: destination});
};
```